# Using grep to find first two numbers of IP addresses?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting, grep

I'm trying to figure out how to use grep to pull out only the first two numbers of an IP address in a list. I've got a routine that is isolating the log entires (from Exim) that I need, now I just need to determine what the first two IP address numbers are.

I've tried this:

```
unique_ips2=$(grep "$email" tmp_exim|grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"|sort -u)
```

But instead of just getting the first two numbers in a 4 IP set, this is giving me 8 pairs of numbers, i.e the first two and the last two of each IP.

The original statement uses `sed` to pull out the complete IPs, like so:

```
unique_ips=$(grep "$email" tmp_exim|sed 's/.*[[]\([0-9\.]*\)[]].*/\1/'|sort -u|wc -l)
```

But I don't have any familiarity with `sed` at all, and have no idea how to modify this statement as every attempt has only caused errors.

Comment: Does *tmp_exim* just contain IP addresses line per line? If not, please show us an example content.

Answer (score 2):

For a plain list of IPv4 addresses a simple `cut` should be enough:

> cut -d "." -f -2 tmp_exim | sort -u

Answer (score 1):

Exim log files contain lots of data on each line.  Continuing on with the OP's approach for separating out the IP information, consider:

```
unique_ips2=$(grep "$email" tmp_exim | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.' | sort -u)
```

The first change above is to put the regex inside single-quotes so that bash doesn't mess with it.  The second change is escaping the period.  Unescaped, period means any character but we want it to mean only a literal period.  The third change is to add a (literal) period at the end of the regex.  This prevents the regex from matching the last two numbers of an IP address.

`sed` can also do this well:

```
unique_ips2=$(sed -nr "/$email/"' s/.*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\..*/\1/p' tmp_exim | sort -u)
```

The option `-n` tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to and `-r` tells it, for convenience, to use extended regex.  (OSX is different: replace`-r` with `-E`.)  The expression `/$email/` tells `sed` to operate only on lines that have that email address in them.  (When using `sed`, `grep` is often superfluous.)  The meat of the command is the substitution `s/.*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\..*/\1/p`.  This looks for any text at all (`.*`) followed by a literal open square bracket (in my exim logs, the IP address is always preceded by an open square bracket) follow by a number, a period, another number, a period, and then anything at all (`.*`).  The number-period-number regex is grouped inside parentheses.  This means that we can refer to it as `\1` (it is the only parens grouping so it is also the first).  So, the substitute command replaces the whole line with just the first two numbers of the IP address.  The final `p` in the command tells `sed` to print the result if the substitution occurs.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much. We ended up inserting the longer sed line suggested above, and now I am working this into the overall detection script.